# GRUB 2 failure - boot repair won't fix

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

As stated in the title, GRUB 2 has failed. I've tried all possible ways I could find, but to no avail. When I ran boot repair from my bootable usb stick, the link given to me was http://paste.ubuntu.com/13213008/
Any help would be appreciated :)
thnx

Comment: Is it a new installation of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Ubuntu is not or not correctly installed ... so follow these installation instructions :

(**sda2** where it should be installed to ... in your pastebin output it shows  **unknown filesystem**)

Boot from Ubuntu installation media and select the option **Try Ubuntu without installing**.

When the desktop appears open **GParted** and format **sda1** with **fat32** and **sda2** with **ext4**.

Click on **Install Ubuntu** to start the installation, when asked choose **Something else**.

Select **sda2** for Ubuntu - choose **ext4 filesystem** and set the **mount option `/` (root)**.

Select **sda** for the GRUB **boot loader** as the installation **location**.

After having completed everything start the installation process.

Recommended : Avoid using 3rd party tools like boot-repair - better use built-in capabilities !

Comment: when I attempt to install after the following the instructions, it says "no root system defined" I was confused by this because I checked and triple checked that I had selected /boot as the mount poiint. However if I just typed in "/" it would let me install. Fix?

Comment: nvm im dumb :P lol

Comment: @LukeButtz : The mount point is NOT /boot - the mount point for the system is / ... you don't have to type / ... you can select it from the drop down menu ! :)